# Rebuild CupertinoTabBar content on CupertinoTabBar item change

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, tabs

I have a cupertinoTabBar (wrapped in CupertinoTabScaffold) which contains 3 tabs.

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
    tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      items: getBarItems(),
    ),
    tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return BaseHomeState.widgetOptions[index];
    },
  ),
```

(BaseHomeState is an abstract state I use to share code with both android & iOS platform)

widgetOptions :

```
static final List<Widget> widgetOptions = <Widget>[
   const FormPage(),
   const DraftsPage(),
   const SettingsPage(),
];
```

Those 'Page' are StatelessWidgets which contain BlocProviders with Platform Dedicated StatefulWidgets as child.

I need my tab's content (widgetOptions) to relaunch build method every time I switch tab which is not the case now. The problem is, sometimes the DraftsPage content must be updated due to changes on FormPage (user can save form drafts and see those on DraftPage). But those two pages aren't linked anywhere :

I just want my DraftsPage to fetch database (thanks to a rebuild) everytime I select its tab and not only the first time.

Do you have an idea? :)

Comment: "DraftsPage content must be updated due to changes on FormPage" - does not sound like it should be a stateful widget by definition?

Comment: Hm said like this, Yes. But it's a little bit more difficult. When you write in a form, you can save it as draft. Then it's saved in database. All I want is that as soon as I go to the DraftsPage Tab, the build method is launched & a database fetch is done. Nothing complicated, no event listener etc.. (I will edit my first message)

Comment: I believe that in Flutter the best way to do something like that is converting it to a stateful widget,  manage the state at the appropriate place in your widget tree and use the notifier / provider / consumer schema.

Comment: Thanks. But that's not working in my context.

Comment: in my example, those widgets are rebuilding. and i didnt wrap with const. doyou want  changes without navigating?